# Mapping a key to AltGr with KDE On Ubuntu

Tags: x11, kde, keyboard-layout

Is there a way to Assign `AltGr` to the right <kbd>Win</kbd> key?

I'm Using KDE Workspace in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test this, because I don't have a right <kbd>Win</kbd>, but you can check out `System Settings` > `Hardware` > `Input Devices` > `Keyboard` > `Layouts` > `Shortcuts for Switching Layout` > 3rd level shortcuts.

This will open up `Advanced` > `Key to choose 3rd level`. Select `Right Win`.

[image: Screenshot of system settings]

Comment: Is there a way to test the AltGr? My keyboard does not have one and if right win  works as AltGr I don't know how to test it.

Comment: You have to be using a layout that utilises AltGr, such as "English (international AltGr dead keys)", which you can specify in `Layouts` > `Configure layouts`. Try holding right Win with various other keys. e.g. AltGr+a = á; AltGr+c = ©.

Comment: `right Win + cc ` prints `č`. A bit mysterious!

Comment: Oh. That's odd. It's functioning as the compose key then. Did you hold the Win key down when pressing (the first) c? Also, do you have other settings in Advanced, specifically in "Position of Compose key"? The compose key works after release, whereas AltGr is a modifier like Shift.

Comment: yes. Position of Compose key was checked for ‍`Right Win`. Now `right win + c` prints `©`. But I have a problem English (international AltGr dead keys): the chacacter (`) is printed hardly or is not printed at all!

Comment: @MinimusHeximus What do you mean by "printed hardly"? Do you mean that it *does* work sometimes?

Comment: here in this comment box it does not print anything (however normal English does). But in other KDE text boxes it is printed if I press the key several times.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus That's bizarre. I'm not sure what to make of that. I can't imagine how it would change the keys so inconsistently like that. Perhaps try a restart?

Comment: I restated but it is as before. I checked /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/. Its layout uses `dead_grave` instead of `grave`. Probably I have to change it or create a new edited layout.

Comment: Nice find! That's quite possible. It's odd though, because I also use layout=us; variant=altgr-intl (you can check if it's identical to my setup with `setxkbmap -query`). From `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us`, this includes `us(intl)`, which, as you point out, has `dead_grave` for the unmodified tilde. However, `altgr-intl` overrides this with normal `grave` (see 7 lines after the first occurrance of this phrase in that file).

Comment: I use `us(intl)`. But something hinders (`). I'm not sure what's wrong with it. I try replacing `dead_grave` with `grave` to see if it is checked. btw the question above is answered!

Comment: Ah, that might be the difference then. I'm not sure why the GUI wouldn't have selected the same as me. If you replace the files, remember to clear the cache by deleting pre-compiled `*.xkm` files in `/var/lib/xkb`.

Comment: Also, FWIW I specify xkb layouts via `xorg.conf`, because they vary for keyboard. However, I think you should be able to select `altgr-intl` instead of `intl` via the GUI.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by GUI, but this is what I selected: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lTLji.jpg.

Comment: Ah okay. I suggested the different, but similarly-named "International AltGr dead keys" https://i.imgur.com/gsrBq9L.png

Comment: @MinimusHeximus No worries, glad to help!

Comment: I'm going to re'edit the image to see what happens. No need to accept: [related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237245/252206)